# Numpy - asarray of a list, dimension not automatically set in the vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers

```
l = [ 1 , 3, 5]
```

I want to convert it to a numpy array vector

```
import numpy as np
vec = np.asarray(l)
```

But the dimensions of vec is not set

```
vec.shape
Answer: (3,)
```

I know I can do

```
vec.shape = (vec.shape[0], 1)
```

But is there any faster, shorter way to set the second dimension to one?

Comment: What's your use case? Are you coming from Matlab? You're getting a 1D array, which let's you forget whether you need column or row vectors, because it just works (in dot products, setting rows or columns of a 2D array...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> vec = np.asarray(l).reshape((1,-1)) 
>>> vec.shape
(1, 3)
```

I think is what you want ... maybe

Comment: Exactly! Why did you put double parenthesis ((1,-1))? And what does -1 mean?

Comment: -1 is the default size so it will work with any size list ... other wise you would need to put the size there (3 in this case ... ) the argument to reshape is a (width,height) tuple ...

Comment: oh Ive always just given it a tuple :P

Comment: @user1506145 I don't believe this is what the OP wants... shape should be `(3, 1)` to make a column vector.

Comment: I am really tired of reshaping every vector after np.asarray(). Do you know if there is an alternative way to get full dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way to read this (for me) is to use `np.newaxis`:

```
a = np.array([1,3,5])
a.shape
#(3,)

b = a[np.newaxis,...]
print b
#[[1, 3, 4]]

b.shape
#(1, 3)
```

But this is not a column vector..., maybe you want:

```
c = a[...,np.newaxis]
print c
#[[1],
# [3],
# [4]]

c.shape
#(3, 1)
```

You can also use `None` instead of `np.newaxis` wherever you want the new axis:

```
a[...,None]
#[[1],
# [3],
# [4]]
```